# Is there a Query to get result as sorted result set based on the count of value that is stored as comma separated in a field?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, symfony4

Hi i have recently started working on Symfony 4. I have 4 tables designed by following EAV rules. eav_entity, eav_attribute, eav_entity_instance, eav_value_text having following fields.

```
mysql> select * from eav_entity;
+----+---------+---------+---------------------+---------------------+
| id | code    | label   | created_at          | updated_at          |
+----+---------+---------+---------------------+---------------------+
|  5 | user    | User    | 2020-05-07 21:53:48 | 2020-05-07 21:53:48 |
|  6 | project | Project | 2020-05-07 21:53:48 | 2020-05-07 21:53:48 |
+----+---------+---------+---------------------+---------------------+


mysql> select * from eav_attribute;
+----+-----------+-----------------+-----------+-----------+-------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| id | entity_id | code            | type      | is_unique | is_required | created_at          | updated_at          |
+----+-----------+-----------------+-----------+-----------+-------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| 33 |         5 | full_name       | text      |         0 |           1 | 2020-05-07 21:59:20 | 2020-05-07 21:59:20 |
| 34 |         5 | email           | text      |         1 |           1 | 2020-05-07 22:00:32 | 2020-05-07 22:00:32 |
| 35 |         5 | phone_number    | varchar   |         1 |           1 | 2020-05-07 22:00:51 | 2020-05-07 22:00:51 |
| 36 |         5 | password        | varchar   |         1 |           1 | 2020-05-07 22:01:02 | 2020-05-07 22:01:02 |
| 43 |         6 | project_name    | varchar   |         0 |           1 | 2020-05-11 00:49:41 | 2020-05-11 00:49:41 |
| 44 |         6 | project_id      | varchar   |         1 |           1 | 2020-05-11 00:49:41 | 2020-05-11 00:49:41 |
| 45 |         6 | project_manager | varchar   |         0 |           1 | 2020-05-11 00:49:41 | 2020-05-11 00:49:41 |
| 46 |         6 | players         | text      |         0 |           1 | 2020-05-11 00:49:41 | 2020-05-11 00:49:41 |
| 47 |         5 | is_admin        | boolean   |         0 |           0 | 2020-05-12 10:21:33 | 2020-05-12 10:21:33 |
| 49 |         5 | is_enabled      | boolean   |         0 |           0 | 2020-05-16 17:34:03 | 2020-05-16 17:34:03 |
| 51 |         5 | last_activity   | timestamp |         0 |           0 | 2020-05-16 22:20:45 | 2020-05-16 22:20:45 |
| 58 |         5 | experience      | varchar   |         0 |           0 | 2020-05-18 18:26:30 | 2020-05-18 18:26:30 |
| 59 |         5 | branch          | varchar   |         0 |           0 | 2020-05-18 22:18:53 | 2020-05-18 22:18:53 |
+----+-----------+-----------------+-----------+-----------+-------------+---------------------+---------------------+

mysql> select * from eav_entity_instance;
+----+-----------+---------------------+---------------------+
| id | entity_id | created_at          | updated_at          |
+----+-----------+---------------------+---------------------+
| 38 |         5 | 2020-05-16 22:21:50 | 2020-05-16 22:21:50 |
| 39 |         5 | 2020-05-17 21:52:03 | 2020-05-17 21:52:03 |
| 40 |         5 | 2020-05-17 21:53:10 | 2020-05-17 21:53:10 |
| 41 |         6 | 2020-05-17 21:57:24 | 2020-05-17 21:57:24 |
| 42 |         6 | 2020-05-17 22:20:38 | 2020-05-17 22:20:38 |
| 53 |         5 | 2020-05-19 21:47:32 | 2020-05-19 21:47:32 |
| 54 |         5 | 2020-05-19 21:49:07 | 2020-05-19 21:49:07 |
| 55 |         5 | 2020-05-19 21:49:09 | 2020-05-19 21:49:09 |
| 56 |         5 | 2020-05-20 20:57:05 | 2020-05-20 20:57:05 |
+----+-----------+---------------------+---------------------+

mysql> select * from eav_value_text;
+----+-------------+--------------+----------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| id | instance_id | attribute_id | value                | created_at          | updated_at          |
+----+-------------+--------------+----------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| 63 |          38 |           33 | Raj                  | 2020-05-16 22:21:50 | 2020-05-16 22:21:50 |
| 64 |          38 |           34 | raj@gmail.com        | 2020-05-16 22:21:50 | 2020-05-16 22:21:50 |
| 65 |          39 |           33 | Ank                  | 2020-05-17 21:52:03 | 2020-05-17 21:52:03 |
| 66 |          39 |           34 | ank@gmail.com        | 2020-05-17 21:52:03 | 2020-05-17 21:52:03 |
| 67 |          40 |           33 | Bas                  | 2020-05-17 21:53:10 | 2020-05-17 21:53:10 |
| 68 |          40 |           34 | bas@gmail.com        | 2020-05-17 21:53:10 | 2020-05-17 21:53:10 |
| 69 |          41 |           46 | 38                   | 2020-05-17 21:57:24 | 2020-05-17 21:57:24 |
| 70 |          42 |           46 | 38,39                | 2020-05-17 22:20:38 | 2020-05-17 22:20:38 |
| 81 |          53 |           34 | vij@gmail.com        | 2020-05-19 21:47:32 | 2020-05-19 21:47:32 |
| 82 |          54 |           34 | abd@gmail.com        | 2020-05-19 21:49:07 | 2020-05-19 21:49:07 |
| 83 |          55 |           34 | jam@gmail.com        | 2020-05-19 21:49:09 | 2020-05-19 21:49:09 |
| 84 |          53 |           33 | Vij                  | 2020-05-19 21:59:35 | 2020-05-19 21:59:35 |
| 85 |          54 |           33 | Abd                  | 2020-05-19 22:04:59 | 2020-05-19 22:04:59 |
| 86 |          56 |           34 | raja@gmail.com       | 2020-05-20 20:57:05 | 2020-05-20 20:57:05 |
| 87 |          55 |           33 | Jam                  | 2020-05-21 16:07:30 | 2020-05-21 16:07:30 |
+----+-------------+--------------+----------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

Project and user are two entities that have different attributes.

In eav_entity_instance you can see that user and employee have different attribute_id.

My problem is i need to generate the query such that instance_id of user is returned in a manner that no of projects user participates in.

In eav_attribute table there is a attribute called players which has id as 46.

The value of this is stored in eav_value_text table where instance_id of user is comma separated.

Can anyone help me with querying such that each instance_id is matched in players comma separated value and count how many project each user is participating in and result is returned in sorted order of count.

For example instance_id 38 is of user and it is repeated in 2 projects whoe's instance_id is 41 and 42. So Similarly user with instance id 39 is found only in one value which is 42.

So since user with instance id 38 has 2 projects and user with instance id has 1 project, result should be like below if we sort it in ASC and reverse if we sort it in DESC.

```
+---+
|id +
+---+
|38 |
|39 |
+---+
```

Comment: Best suggestion would be DONT store id's in a comma seperated list in a single mysql column. It breaks the normalisation rules. And of course it makes writing a query to make useful use of that list ALMOST impossible

Comment: Yeah i agree RiggsFolly, now that i have messed it up i just need to put the fire down.

Comment: Often the simplest way to get out of this mess is to do quite a bit of the processing in PHP

Comment: Sample results are always helpful to people on StackOverflow who would help you.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestiono  RiggsFolly and O.Jones, I have updated my question with sample reuslt.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad

Answer (score 0):

In SQL server you could use the function STRING_SPLIT but a quick google search revealed that it does not exist in MySql. But my search result did point me to [this site](https://www.sisense.com/blog/splitting-comma-separated-values-in-mysql/) You could use the information in the following manner to solve your problem ([SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/607cf1/1/0)):

```
CREATE TABLE ProjectMembers 
    ( instance_id int
    , value varchar(500)
    );
INSERT INTO ProjectMembers(instance_id, value)
VALUES    (41, '38')
        , (42, '38,39');

/* Be sure that the amount of numbers in this table is at least as long as the 
   maximum amount of project members in a project */
CREATE TABLE Numbers
  (Number int);
INSERT INTO Numbers(Number)
VALUES (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (7), (8), (9);

SELECT Member, COUNT(*) AS Nr FROM ( 
  SELECT 
    instance_id, 
    substring_index(
      substring_index(value, ',', Number), 
      ','
      , -1
    ) AS Member
  FROM ProjectMembers
  JOIN Numbers
    ON char_length(value) 
      - char_length(replace(value, ',', '')) 
      >= Number - 1
) t
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY Nr DESC;
```